# heroku sequelize: command not found

Tags: mysql, node.js, heroku, sequelize.js

I have installed sequelize cli using the following command

```
npm install -g sequelize-cli
```

It works fine on localhost

But when I deploy to heroku and try to run migrations

I get error

```
sequelize: command not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The package `sequelize-cli` is installed globally on your system so it's working on your system without any problem.
- You can not run a `script` that is installed on your system, on the Heroku.
- Since `Heroku CLI` is made to accomplish the operation related to Heroku dynos only i.e. you can only run commands that are predefined in `Heroku CLI`
- To run a script on `Heroku` you have to define it in `package` and when `Heroku` will deploy your app it will automatically run that script.

#### For example:

If you want to run `db:migrate` using `sequelize-cli` then do the following steps:

- add `sequelize-cli` as a `dependency` in your `package.json`
- add `migrate: "sequelize db:migrate"` in the scripts.

I am not sure for what purpose you want to run this command. But to run a script on `Heroku` you have to define it in your package and `Heroku` will do the rest.

Answer (score 3):

As for me I was trying to run sequelize DB migration to heroku postgress database. As per earlier documentations, or maybe what you tried, was to run the command `heroku run sequelize db:migrate`

This however is what seems to work now  `heroku run npx sequelize-cli db:migrate`

Comment: Or also you can define in your Procfile: `release: npx sequelize-cli db:migrate`, in order to run this everytime you deploy